# SQLAlchemy unusual not null failure when appending to a relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having a very odd error with SQLAlchemy. I've removed as much of my code as possible to narrow down the issue, and removing any more will cause the error to disappear. I was able to reproduce the issue on another PC with a fresh pip install of SQLAlchemy (on Python 2.7).

If I do any variant of appending something like this:

```
python = Application(name='Python')
python.versions.append(ApplicationVersion(version=27))
session.add(python)
session.commit()

#or

python = Application(name='Python')
session.add(python)
session.commit()
python.versions.append(ApplicationVersion(version=27))
session.commit()
```

I get this error (if I don't remove anything else from the code):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: ApplicationVersion.application_id
[SQL: INSERT INTO "ApplicationVersion" (application_id, version_int) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: (None, 27)]
```

However, like I mentioned, it works perfectly if I remove anything. For example, by removing the docstring of this below function, it will assign `application_id` correctly and work as expected.

```
@contextmanager
def Session():
    """Setup session to allow for usage with a context manager."""
    session = _Session()
    yield session
    session.close()
```

I have literally no clue what's going on. As a disclaimer, the other PC I tested is on the same work network, but since I'm testing with `sqlite`, I can't imagine it being something network based.

Here is the code to reproduce the error (it's a single file joined from multiple ones):

```
######### CONNECT.PY #######
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


class BaseTable(object):
    """General things to apply to each table.

    Help: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html
    """
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        """Set the table name to that of the model."""
        return cls.__name__


if 'DATABASE_URL' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'sqlite://'

Engine = create_engine(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])

Base = declarative_base(bind=Engine, cls=BaseTable)

_Session = sessionmaker(bind=Base.metadata.bind)


@contextmanager
def Session():
    """Setup session to allow for usage with a context manager."""
    session = _Session()
    yield session
    session.close()


########## MODELS.PY ###########
import time
import os
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, SmallInteger, String, Text
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint, Table, event
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship, validates


class Category(Base):
    row_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Category.row_id'), nullable=True)

    parent = relationship('Category', foreign_keys=parent_id, remote_side=row_id)
    children = relationship('Category')

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('name', 'parent_id', name='unique_name_parent'),
    )

    @hybrid_property
    def fullname(self):
        parent = self.parent
        visited = set()
        chain = [self.name]
        while parent:
            if parent in visited:
                break
            visited.add(parent)
            chain.append(parent.name)
            parent = parent.parent

        return '.'.join(chain[::-1])

    def __init__(self, name, collection, parent=None, creator=None, **kwargs):
        super(Category, self).__init__(name=name, collection=collection, parent=parent, creator=creator, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{cls} "{fullname}">'.format(
            cls=self.__class__.__name__,
            fullname=self.fullname,
        )


class Application(Base):
    row_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(16), nullable=False)
    versions = relationship('ApplicationVersion', order_by='ApplicationVersion.version_int')


class ApplicationVersion(Base):
    row_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    application_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Application.row_id'), nullable=False)
    version_int = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    application = relationship('Application', foreign_keys=application_id)

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('application_id', 'version_int', name='unique_application_version'),
    )

    def __init__(self, version, application=None, **kwargs):
        super(ApplicationVersion, self).__init__(application=application, version_int=version, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{cls} "{application} {version}">'.format(
            cls=self.__class__.__name__,
            application=self.application.name,
            version=self.version_int,
        )

    def __eq__(self, num):
        return self.version_int == num

    def __neq__(self, num):
        return self.version_int != num


######## TEST.PY ########
Base.metadata.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Session() as session:

        # Setup programs and versions
        python = Application(name='Python')
        python.versions.append(ApplicationVersion(version=27))
        session.add(python)
        session.commit()

        print python.versions
```

These are various actions that will stop the error:

- Remove docstring from `BaseTable` or `Session`
- Remove `if 'DATABASE_URL' not in os.environ:`
- Replace `create_engine(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])` with
  `create_engine('sqlite://')`
- Remove `Category`
- Remove relationships from `Category`
- Remove `fullname`, `__init__` or `__repr__` from `Category`
- Remove `__init__`, `__repr__`, `__eq__` or `__neq__` from
  `ApplicationVersion`

Any help would be appreciated as it's driving me a little crazy. I can get around the issue by using `session.add(ApplicationVersion(python, 27))`, but I would like to know what is actually going on here, as I've never seen Python behave like this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem to be with the custom constructor that you've defined on `ApplicationVersion`:

```py
def __init__(self, version, application=None, **kwargs):
    super(ApplicationVersion, self).__init__(application=application, version_int=version, **kwargs)
```

Specifically, you allow for a default value of `None` for `ApplicationVersion.application`. I'm not sure what value this serves to you as the default constructor doesn't require that you pass an explicit value for any of the model's fields, and so if it's not provided it will be `None` when accessed anyway.

Then in this line in your test:

```py
python.versions.append(ApplicationVersion(version=27))
```

... you explicitly create an ApplicationVersion object with `application=None` due to the constructor, but at the same time, append it to the `python.versions` collection. The manner in which these relationships resolve foreign key values appears to be inconsistent, so sometimes it's trying to flush with `application_id=1` which is the pk of the new `Application` object, and other times it's trying to flush with `application_id=None` as the constructor dictates. But `application_id` is not nullable:

```py
application_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Application.row_id'), nullable=False)
```

... and that is when you get the `IntegrityError`.

SQLAlchemy must make some distinction between explicitly setting a relationship attribute to `None` and it never having been set at all, because if you stop setting `application` to `None` in your constructor, the problem stops:

```py
def __init__(self, version, **kwargs):
    super(ApplicationVersion, self).__init__(version_int=version, **kwargs)
```

I was able to whittle your example down to this generic example (Python 3 I'm sorry, so you'll need to adjust the `print` calls):

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

Base = declarative_base()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship('Child')


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    num = Column(Integer)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), nullable=False)
    parent = relationship('Parent')

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(parent=parent, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    error_cnt = 0
    success_cnt = 0
    for _ in range(20):
        s = Session()
        try:
            parent = Parent()
            parent.children.append(Child())
            s.add(parent)
            s.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            error_cnt += 1
        else:
            success_cnt += 1
        finally:
            s.close()
    print('errors', error_cnt)
    print('successes', success_cnt)
```

When you run that, you should get random counts of successes and errors. Then delete `Child.__init__()` method and it works all the time.

Comment: Ah thanks a bunch for taking the time to check it out, that is very obscure but makes total sense haha (I wonder if its a bug or just a limitation). I guess when making a model then, I'll have to decide whether appending or creating is more pythonic, instead of trying to account for both.